# Scrollspy: Can get to work in JSfiddle but not on actual page?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I am having an issue with  twitter bootstraps scrollspy. I can currently get it to work (remade an example) at http://jsfiddle.net/VLBMV/2/ which is awesome. However, When I convert it to an actual page of any sort. It only makes the last element in the navigation active.

** Edit here is a live example of it failing with the code below:
http://reageek.ca/dev/test.html

Here is my code(minus the doctype):

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#navbar">
<div>
    <div id="post1" class="box">
        <h1>Post 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="post2" class="box">
        <h1>Post 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="post3" class="box">
        <h1>Post 3</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#post1">Post 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#post2">Post 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#post3">Post 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#navbar').scrollspy();
});
</script>
```

Also here is the contents of my test.css nothing fancy here, just grey boxes

```
   @import url(http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css);
.box{
margin: 20px; padding: 15px;
background: #eee;
height: 500px;
}
#navbar{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0; left: 20px;
width: 100%;
background: #fff;
}
.nav li a{
float: left;
width: 80px;
padding: 15px 0;
}
.nav li a:hover{
color: #f33 !important;
background: none;
}
.nav li.active a{
color: #f55;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Could anyone shed some light why this fails?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Misspelling?

```
$('#nabar').scrollspy();
```

probably should be

```
$('#navbar').scrollspy();
```

Everything else looks fine as far as I can tell... Though it is misspelled in the fiddle too and still working.

Comment: woops on the spelling my bad I have corrected that small mistake. However, I am still getting the same results locally and on a server, but the js fiddle still works. I really do not get why.

Comment: @user1452407 I just tried http://reageek.ca/dev/test.html and it's seeming to work now...